# How to Update the Value of Vertex in Gremlin Server ( Titan 1.0)

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm having a vertex with following details:

> http://localhost:8182/?gremlin=g.V(4192)

```
{

"requestId": "6ce01f3b-f623-41f6-bb03-dd56014e0701",
"status": 

{

"message": "",
"code": ​200,
"attributes": { }

},
"result": 
{

"data": 

[

{

"id": ​4192,
"label": "person",
"type": "vertex",
"properties": 

{

"name": 

[

{
    "id": "170-38g-sl",
    "value": "marko2"
}

],
"age": 
[

                    {
                        "id": "1l8-38g-28lh",
                        "value": ​29
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": { }
}

}
```

I want to update the Name of the vertex :

I tried following query :

> g.V(4192).setProperty('name','William')

But it is not updating , it is giving error

```
{

 "message": "Error encountered evaluating script: g.V(4192).setProperty('name','William')"

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no method called "setProperty()" on a `Traversal`. You would do:

```
g.V(4192).property('name','William')
```

Please see the full list of steps in the [TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#graph-traversal-steps).

You could also work with the Vertex directly and do:

```
v = g.V(4192).next()
v.property('name','william')
```

Comment: How can I update multiple values at once ? i tried g.V(4192).property('name','William2','age',30). but it is not working

Comment: Try `g.V(4192).property('name','William2').property('age',30)`

Answer (score 9):

In case the `property()` method generates an array of values rather than updating the value, use `Cardinality` like so:

```
g.V(4192)v.property(Cardinality.single, 'name', 'william').next()
```

This will replace the property value instead of appending into the list.